How to make a 64bit Python interpreter safely available to a Virtualenv in PyCharm if only a 32bit Python version is installed on my machine?
I have Python 3.8.1 as 32 bit version installed on a machine running Windows 10 Pro 64 bit. I am now using PyCharm and created a virtual environment (VE) using Virtualenv. From there, I only have access to one Python interpreter. Running
$ python

>>> import platform

>>> platform.architecture()

in the terminal inside the VE yields
('32bit', 'WindowsPE')

meaning that it is using the globally installed Python.
For my project in the VE, however, I need a 64 bit Python interpreter, as I need Tensorflow and most likely some other 3rd party libraries that might require such an interpreter. Following the official documentation I could install a 64 bit version globally. However, I am afraid that this might cause unforeseeable side effects, making one version get into the way of the other. Another solution might be fully uninstalling my 32 bit Python from my machine and installing a 64 bit version instead. However, posts like this and the likeliness of leftovers as discussed here have scared me off a little bit.

Is there a way to make available a 64 bit Python interpreter (version 3.8.1 would be fine) in such a way that is accessible for Virtualenv environments in PyCharm, just as my 32 bit version is currently, without causing trouble? I would really like to stick to Virtualenv instead of using Anaconda, Poetry or anything else.

Look at using pdm. You can create a virtual environment and select the 64 bit python as the python version for your project.

@blackbrandt "PDM requires Python 3.8+ to be installed." Are you sure it can be run under 32-bit Python?

why do you use 32-bit python?

@phudv I once decided to take the less resource expensive option as I saw no need for the 64 bit version then. Now, my requirements have changed. If there is no possibility of keeping the 32 bit version, then I will be forced to delete it. Please, let me know then how I can fully delete the 32 bit Python without any leftovers.
